# Bivariate Normal Distribution with correlation and mean

Tags: r, normal-distribution

How can I generate k bivariate normal random variables with

- mean=0
- sigma=1 and
- correlation=rho in R?

Comment: To whom it may concern: this question is not off topic, it asks about generating random draws from a distribution.

Comment: It is off topic because it is asking a specific method to do the task in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a bivariate standard normal vector using the inverse CDF.
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathrm{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}\right).
$$
Now,

$$C = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho &1\end{pmatrix}$$
is your covariance matrix. Let $L$ be the Cholesky-decompose of $C$. That means, $L$ is given such that $C = LL^T$. Then, $LX \sim \mathrm{N}(0,C)$.

Here, $L$ can be computed analytically:
$$
L = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \rho &\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Bt , How am I suppose to do this in R ?

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can use the package [rmvtnorm](http://mvtnorm.r-forge.r-project.org/).